# How to load a script with python3 -i, but not have name == main run?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that I want to use with the python shell
(interactivity mode, live interpreter, `python3 [return]`)
and the script I want to have added to the live interpreter (`python3 -i script.py`) has a `if __name__ == '__main__':` in it.
When I load the script the `if __name__` runs.
I have argsprase in the `if __name__` which spits out an error.
So,
I need to be able to add the script to the live interpreter,
but not have certain code in the script run, the code in `if __name__`.

script.py

```py
#/usr/bin/python3

class myExcellentClass:
    def __init__(var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

    def WhatisVar1(self):
        return self.var1

    def WhatisVar2(self):
        return self.var2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    # setup args parse

    # do some stuff here
```

I'm thinking there must be a variable that I can add to `if __name__` that will test for whether the script is being run with `-i` or not.
For example:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__' && is_interactive == false:
    import argparse

    # setup args parse

    # do some stuff here
```

If there is a way to call the live interpreter from in side a python3 script,
I would just add `-i` to the script and have this launch the class added to the live interpreter.

---

I could split out the class into another file.
I would like not to do this if possible.

Example:

scriptA.py

```py
#/usr/bin/python3

class myExcellentClass:
    def __init__(var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

    def WhatisVar1(self):
        return self.var1

    def WhatisVar2(self):
        return self.var2
```

scriptB.py

```py
#/usr/bin/python3

from scriptA import *

if __name__ == '__main__' && is_interactive == false:
    import argparse

    # setup args parse

    # do some stuff here
```

I usually install the script system wide as a byte-code file for efficiency purposes.
(Yes I know that it's not recommend, nor will the pyc work with different versions of python.)
As I only need to use the `-i` for testing and trouble shooting,
I would prepare a solution that would allow me to keep everything in one python file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you are looking for actually exists.

```
from sys import flags
print(flags.interactive)
```

This prints `1` in interactive mode and zero otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Just run `python3` and the type `from script import *`.

a more complete answer here: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)